# The hover state doesn't work properly on animations

Tags: css, animation

I have an element which when the user hover on it (`:hover`), it will animate from left to right, so the element will get off the mouse. So the `:hover` state should back to normal state, but this won't happen. What is wrong?

```
#test {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 20;
    transition: left 1s linear;
}

#test:hover {
    left: 200px;
    background: green;
}
```

[image]

Here is the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bF3FC/1/).

Comment: You found a Chrome bug.  It works in Firefox.

Comment: @SLaks In firefox (version 24 on Windows 8), it works stranger, it reverts back after a while (not immediately after the element get off the mouse).

Comment: Got completely stuck on my mouse in Firefox and turned into a epilepsy flash box. What is the practical use for this?

Comment: @SLaks Also, even when it reverts back to normal state, it should hover again, shouldn't?

Comment: @AndrewClody Actually, I created this demo only to show the hover state remains even the element isn't under the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Within

```
#test:hover {
    left: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

you tell the element to go outside the width of itself and the transition forces it to do so.
If you change the hover transition to `left: 100px;` it will work.

The transition is the master and the hover the slave as you will ;)